# React JS this.props.state is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Don't understand what is wrong with my statement here, I keep looking up the error message on google but i really don't understand the problem.

```
componentDidMount()
{
    fetch('http://192.168.1.33:8080/getprojects/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.props.state({
            projects: data.name
        });
    });
}
```

according to chrome's console it says that

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.props.state is not a function

and points to this:

```
this.props.state({
        projects: data.name
    });
```

I am lost here. New to React JS trying to create a website that fetches data constantly (here i'm trying to fill a list under the format ul li by getting names on my Node Express server)

**EDIT**

here is the complete code before the Return inside the Render function :

```
 class ProjectList extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            projects: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        fetch('http://192.168.1.33:8080/getprojects/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({projects: data.name})
        });
    }

   render () {
    let projects = this.state.projects;
    let liItems = projects.map((project) =>
            <li key={project.name}>{project.name}</li>
        );
```

after that it's just basic HTML

Comment: Are you defining `this.props.state` defined anywhere?

Comment: try `this.setState({projects: data.name})`

Comment: take the time to read the react documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html. I think that you want this.state or this.setState(). But give you some times to do the getting started of the doc :)

Comment: @MohamedRamrami just tried it and now my webpage isn't being printed and the new error is "cannot read property of map of undefined"

Comment: `{projects: data.name}`  That doesn't sound like it's going to be an array.   Did you mean to do -> `{projects: data}`, ?

Comment: @Keith when i do that i get yet another error and this time it's : "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: Your second set of code is different from your first set of code. Which one are you having an issue with?

Comment: @HereticMonkey the second code is different because i modified the first code according to the previous comments

Comment: So... does the second code work? If so, make it an answer. If not, say why. Or better yet, ask a new question with whatever issue you're having with the second code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey no it does not work.... it brings another mistake : "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: Great! Sounds like a great new question to ask, since this question was answered in the comments. You can either write an answer to the original question in the "Your Answer" box, or delete this question. Then click the Ask Question button to ask your new one. Might want to do a search for that error message first though.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting property undefined, because the render function runs before the componentDidMount function. So when it first try to run, the first thing it encounters is this: `let projects = this.state.projects;` and you defined it initially, it's an empty array. So within your render function, remove the line above and replace with:

`if (this.state.projects.length === 0){
    return <div>Loading</div>
}`
So when initially your component will run it will render for a split second the Loading div, and when your array is populated your component with your array will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let liItems = projects.length && projects.map((project) =>
        <li key={project.name}>{project.name}</li>
    );
```

Change like this and in render

```
    render(){
return(
<ul>{liItems}</ul>
)
}
```

If you dont have any projects it renders empty.